# How a pair privatekey and certificate match together in IAIK PKCS11 Wrapper?

Tags: java, pkcs#11, iaik-jce

I want to work with a pkcs11 token in java. Thus, I used "IAIK" as a pkcs11 java wrapper. I can search for objects like keys and certificates but I can't find out which key belongs to which certificate. I used "CryptoKi Manager" for search objects in the token and it shows the connection between a certificate and key like below picture. Then I studied PKCS11 standard, it said there is a field called "certId" that declare this connection but I couldn't find it in "IAIK". Does "IAIK" support this feature in its Certificate object? How?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This connection is via the `CKA_ID` attribute, citing PKCS#11 version 2.20:

> The CKA_ID field is intended to distinguish among multiple keys. In the case of public
>   and private keys, this field assists in handling multiple keys held by the same subject; the
>   key identifier for a public key and its corresponding private key should be the same. The
>   key identifier should also be the same as for the corresponding certificate, if one exists.
>   Cryptoki does not enforce these associations, however. (See Section 10.6 for further
>   commentary.)

Please note that this association is not enforced (YMMV), but sane implementations behave in this way.

Use [Key.getId()](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/objects/Key.html#getId()) and [X509PublicKeyCertificate.getID()](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/objects/X509PublicKeyCertificate.html#getId()) methods in the PKCS#11 wrapper.

With IAIK-provider (note that you need a license) use [IAIKPKCS11Key.getKeyID()](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_provider/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/provider/keys/IAIKPKCS11Key.html#getKeyID()) to pair public and private key objects. I don't know how to get `CKA_ID` value from certificates obtained from [TokenKeyStore](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_provider/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/provider/TokenKeyStore.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Here, there are very good samples: https://github.com/aigens/java-sample-programs/tree/master/JavaSamples/References/iaikPkcs11Wrapper1.2.17/demo/src/demo/pkcs/pkcs11